# How to use a functions parameter as attribute in dot notation with an object

Tags: javascript, string, object, parameters, attributes

I have a function with a parameter which is a string. I want to use this string as an attribut in a object. Here's an example how it would be:

```
var x = "somestring"
function foo(attribute) {  
    someobj.attribute = "something";
}
foo(x);
```

Comment: Try this - someobj[attribute]

Answer (score 5):

Use subscript `[]` notation for the dynamic keys:

```
someobj[attribute] = "something";
```

**CODE**

```
var x = "somestring";
var someobj = {};

function foo(attribute) {
    someobj[attribute] = "something";
}
foo(x);
```

Comment: **Note:** Although it looks like an array, it will make also someobj.somestring accessible, which is a speciality in JavaScript.